# Why does ASP.NET MVC a href onclick fires immediately?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, onclick

```
<a href="" onclick="@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }">
```

Fires immediately at the time of page-load. Why?

Comment: Could there be a onload event that triggers the anchor? Can you provide more details? And also you need a closing tag if you don't have one.

Comment: _Layout.cshtml - something similar to the "Master Page".

Comment: <div>
        <a href="" onclick="@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }">@MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SelectAppropriate("на русском", "in english")</a>
    </div>

Comment: what is the output of `@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }`

Comment: @Reddy void C# method

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }` outputs. I'd imagine it's javascript. You could instead try this:

```
<script>
function doClick() {
@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }
}
</script>

<a href="" onclick="doClick();">
```

Comment: SwapLanguage() is very simple C# method.

Comment: <a href="" onclick="doSwapLanguage();">на русском</a>

Comment: try this: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doSwapLanguage();return false;">на русском</a>`

Answer (score 1):

> Fires immideately at the time of page-load

with this code

```
<a href="" onclick="@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }">
```

`@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }` **is a C# code block which executes immediately** , It will execute normally as it should, you are calling the method, this will actually call the method in your server side. The output of this method will be returned back, if its void it just executes.

If your intention is to execute this Method on click of the anchor tag then you can first call a javascript method on click, And inside this method **do a ajax call to your server code**.

---

---

To make this more clear let me explain you the scenarios.

If at all your method returns something like

```
public string SwapLanguage()
{
  return "testString";
}
```

then the output of this statement

`<a href="" onclick="@{ MultiLanguageProvider.Instance.SwapLanguage(); }">`

after the page loads  would be

```
 <a href="" onclick="testString">
```

Comment: yeah, it must be that way.. but it is not. I've checked step-by-step in debug mode. method fires without clicking on the link - just a the page-load time.

Comment: @52hertz yes it will load as soon as the page loads, Because its a C# code that runs as soon as it loads,  This is expected behavior.

Comment: @52hertz from what I can understand is you need to use AJAX for such functionalities

Comment: I got no exper. in AJAX. ))

Comment: @52hertz it is a small concept, you can learn it quick, But what ever you are trying to do is not the right way, its not how you think it must work..

Comment: what u mean? Are u talking about MultiLanguage class?

Comment: @52hertz small concept refers to AJAX, and other stuff refers to C#